# A finite dimensional vector $V$ is not free as an $\operatorname{End}_{K}(V)$-module

Tags: abstract-algebra, free-modules

I came across questions in the free module section of my abstract algebra text. As on p358 of the text [Algebra: Abstract and Concrete](http://homepage.math.uiowa.edu/%7Egoodman/algebrabook.dir/book.2.6.pdf), the notation $\operatorname{End}_{R}(M)$ denotes the set of all $R$-module endomorphisms of $M$. On to the question:

> Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space over a field $K$, with $n>1.$  Show that $V$ is not free as an $\operatorname{End}_{K}(V)$ module.

I don't understand the difference between a "free"-module vs a '"free" $End_{K}(V)$ module'.  I know that any vector space $W$ over a field $F$ has a basis and hence it is a free $F$-module.  In the case of the stated $n$-dimensional vector space $V$ in the question, how does defining an endomorphism map $\phi:V\rightarrow V$ given by $\phi(rm)=r\phi(m)$ for all $r\in K$ affects whether $V$ can still being a free module.  Or is it because once I defined some sort of endomorphism map $\phi$ between $V$ to itself, whether $V$ can still enjoy being a free module, or a free $\operatorname{End}_{K}(V)$ module?  I think there is something subtle that I am either not understanding or I am missing to see.  I also understand that a vector space over a field is always a free module because it has a basis and it is defined with scalars from a field which is also an integral domain and the coefficients of the elements of the basis are zero divisors.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you rightly say any vector space $V$ is a free module over $K$. The problem refers to now considering $V$ as a module over the different (now noncommutative) ring $\operatorname{End}_K(V)$. A basis for $V$ as a $K$-module need not be a basis for $V$ as an $\operatorname{End}_K(V)$-module, and that's why $V$ may be free over $K$ and not over $\operatorname{End}_K(V)$.
Now on to the actual problem---this follows from a general fact about $R$-modules. Namely, we have:

**Lemma.** Let $R$ be a ring and let $M$ be an $R$-module. If for all $m \in M$ there is a nonzero $r \in R$ such that $r \cdot m = 0$, then $M$ is not a free $R$-module.

*Proof.* For a contradiction suppose that $\mathcal{B} = \{m_1, \ldots, m_n\}$ is an $R$-basis for $M$. Then by hypothesis there exists a nonzero $r \in R$ such that $r \cdot m_1 = 0$: this contradicts $R$-linear independence of $\mathcal{B}$, as desired.

Now given this lemma, your question is answered quickly: we just need to find for each $v \in V$ a nonzero $\phi \in \operatorname{End}_K(V)$ such that $\phi(v) = 0$. (Note that if $\dim V = 1$ then this is impossible, so that's why it is a hypothesis for your problem.) First note that if $v = 0$ then we can choose $\phi$ to be any nonzero endomorphism of $V$. Otherwise $v \not = 0$, and we can extend the set $\{v\}$ to a basis $\mathcal{B} = \{v, b_1, \ldots, b_n\}$ for $V$. Now define a linear map $\phi$ by declaring that $\phi(v) = 0$ and $\phi(b_i) = 1$ for all $1 \leq i \leq n$. Since $n = \dim V > 1$ then $\phi$ is nonzero because $\phi(b_1) = 1$, but on the other hand $\phi(v) = 0$. We conclude by the lemma that $V$ is not a free $\operatorname{End}_K(V)$-module, as you desire.

Comment: I think you mean $\operatorname{End}_K(V)$ instead of $\operatorname{End}_R(V)$, right? And, one question: In order to apply the lemma, we need to know that $\operatorname{End}_K(V)$ is an integral domain, but that's not the case, isn't? For example, when $n=2$, $\big(\begin{smallmatrix} 1&0\\1&0 \end{smallmatrix} \big) \big(\begin{smallmatrix} 0&0\\1&1 \end{smallmatrix} \big) = \big(\begin{smallmatrix} 0&0\\0&0 \end{smallmatrix} \big)$ says that $K^{2\times2} [\cong \operatorname{End}_K(V)]$ is not an integral domain.

Comment: @azif00 Of course you are right: $\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$ is even simpler. I got a bit confused with another question of Seth---hopefully things are fixed now.

Comment: @KeeleyHoek sorry for my non prompt reply.  I got thee question from here the text: Algebra: 
 Abstract and Concrete http://homepage.math.uiowa.edu/~goodman/algebrabook.dir/book.2.6.pdf   I am confused whether how to handle putting an endomorphic ring over a vector space and how that affects its status as a free module.  I looked everywhere and there are a bunch theorems that states that a vector space over a field K is a free module.  I thought the question wants me to consider endomorphic mapping of the vector space and illustrate what happens to it algebraically.

Comment: @KeeleyHoek in your answer, you stated for the case "Otherwise $v \not = 0$, and we can extend the set $\{v\}$ to a basis $\mathcal{B} = \{v, b_1, \ldots, b_n\}$ for $V$."  If $v\neq 0$ as you stated, why would I still  need to extend it to a basis.  I thought we already have $V$ as a $n$ dimensional vector space, can't I just using the exchange lemma to fix all the elements in the spanning set from $V$ to make it all linear independent?

Comment: @SethMai For your first question I think I have answered this in a comment on a different question of yours which I'll just repeat here: Well, the way I would think about it is that when we equip the set $V$ with two different module structures, one with a $K$-action and one with a $K[x]$-action, we formally just get two different modules which we (somewhat confusingly) both denote again by $V$. It's fine if one of these two different modules is free while the other is not.

Comment: @SethMai As for your section question, the point of extending the set $\{v\}$ into a basis was that I explicitly wanted a basis which included $v$, because I wanted to define a linear map which sent $v$ to zero. I completely agree with you to the extent that it would also be fine to say: "Choose a basis for $V$ which contains $v$." Does this make sense?

Comment: @KeeleyHoek I just want to make I understand that I can choose basis elements $\mathcal{B} = \{v, b_1, \ldots, b_{n-1}\} from the beginning.

Comment: @SethMai Yes that's right all I need is that for each nonzero $v \in V$ there exists a basis for $V$ which contains $v$. As long as you can find some way to prove that then we agree and are on the same page. :)

Comment: @KeeleyHoek the lemma you used.  Does it appear in any reference.

Comment: @SethMai Ah sorry my formatting is bad but actually the next paragraph beginning "*Proof.*" is the proof of that lemma! Then the next paragraph which begins "Now given this lemma..." is after the end of the proof. So the proof of the lemma is very short, but it is useful for your problems today.

Comment: (You will note that I have basically used the same idea in another of your questions where we appealed to the Cayley-Hamilton theorem.)

Comment: @KeeleyHoek until I came across this question and the various responses and comments, I just realised that I somehow remembered the characteristic polynomial, and that I totally forgotten about the minimum polynomial in Jordan Canonical form.  I thought that the term characteristic polynomial is used also for the minimum polynomial in the context of JCF.  Also, some linear algebra text calls it the "minimal polynomial", but in the field section of many abstract algebra text, the notion of minimal polynomial also appears.

Comment: Yes I would definitely suggest to treat the characteristic polynomial and minimal polynomial as names for different concepts: the minimal polynomial is the monic polynomial $p$ of minimal degree such that $p(T) = 0$, so always divides the characteristic polynomial by the Cayley-Hamilton theorem, but they need not be equal.

Comment: @KeeleyHoek ah okay okay.  I will make sure to remember this.  Seriously, either maybe in a differential equations course, I probably have not used the minimal polynomial anywhere else until now.  At my university, modules don't come up until graduate level algebra.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132133/discussion-between-seth-mai-and-keeley-hoek).