# The direct sum of $n$-copies of a $K$-vector space $V$ is a free $\operatorname{End}_{R}(V)$-module

Tags: abstract-algebra, free-modules

I came across questions in the free module section of my abstract algebra text. In the text, the notation $\operatorname{End}_{R}(M)$ denotes the set of all $M$-module endomorphisms of $M$. On to the question:

> Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space over a field $K$.  Show that $V^{n}$ (the direct sum of $n$ copies of $V$) is a free module over $\operatorname{End}_{R}(V)$.

My question is: How would having the direct sum of $n$ copies of $V$ make $V^{n}$ into a free module over $\operatorname{End}_{R}(V)$? If $n=1$, then won't we just have the case for $V$ simply as an $n$-dimensional vector space over a field $K$, and we are back at the situation in the question I posted here: [Question about finite dimensional vector spaces and free $End_{K}(V)$ module](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4326057/question-about-finite-dimensional-vector-spaces-and-free-end-kv-module)

Comment: I think you missed that the dimension of $V$ is equal to the power od $V$ being taken. Hint: matrices.

Comment: @KeeleyHoek I got the question from [Algebra: Abstract and Concrete, p352 of text](http://homepage.math.uiowa.edu/~goodman/algebrabook.dir/book.2.6.pdf)  Thank you for your help with my other questions

Comment: @paulblartmathcop the dimension of each $V$ is $n$, and if there are $n$ copies of $V$, then won't I need $n$ copies of the same basis, each one consisting of $n$ basis elements and each vector space $V$ is not a free module over $End_{K}(V)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $n = 1$ (note that $n$ also has to be the dimension of $V$) then actually the other question doesn't apply, because it requires $n > 1$.

At any rate, let's check this. First note that by the definition of the direct sum of $R$-modules, the module action of $\operatorname{End}_K(V)$ on $V^n$ is just to act on each factor separately. That is, for any $\phi \in \operatorname{End}_K(V)$ and $v = (v_1, \ldots, v_n) \in V^n$ we have
$$
\phi \cdot v := (\phi(v_1), \ldots, \phi(v_n)).
$$
Ok, now given this definition we are supposed to concoct a basis for $V^n$ *as a module over $\operatorname{End}_K(V)$*. As a guess, let's pick a fixed basis $\mathcal{B} = \{b_1, \ldots, b_n\}$ of $V$ as *a module over $V$*. We'll use this for our basis for $V^n$: let's try the set $\{(b_1, \ldots, b_n)\} \subset V^n$ containing just $1$ element.

There are two things to check: first, $\operatorname{End}_K(V)$-linear independence. Thus suppose that
$$
\phi \cdot  (b_1, \ldots, b_n) = 0
$$
for some $\phi \in \operatorname{End}_K(V)$ (note that the definition of linear independence for a set containing a single element is particularly simple). We need to check that $\phi = 0$. To see this now just note that the above equation implies that $\phi(b_i) = 0$ for all $i$. But then $\phi$ is a linear map $V \to V$ which maps a basis of $V$ to zero! Hence $\phi = 0$, as desired.

It just remains to check that the set $\{(b_1, \ldots, b_n)\} \subset V^n$ is $\operatorname{End}_K(V)$-spanning. Thus now let $v = (v_1, \ldots, v_n) \in V^n$ be arbitrary. We need to produce $\phi \in \operatorname{End}_K(V)$ such that $\phi \cdot (b_1, \ldots, b_n) = (v_1, \ldots, v_n)$. But again since the set $\{b_1, \ldots, b_n\}$ is a basis for $V$ we may simply define a linear map $\phi : V \to V$ by declaring that $\phi(b_i) = v_i$ for all $i$. Then indeed $\phi \cdot (b_1, \ldots, b_n) = (v_1, \ldots, v_n)$, as desired. This completes the proof.

---

In summary, we have shown that $V^n$ is a free $\operatorname{End}_K(V)$-module with a basis consisting of one element. This actually (always) means that $V^n$ and $\operatorname{End}_K(V)$ are isomorphic $\operatorname{End}_K(V)$-modules. (Note that any ring $R$, including $R = \operatorname{End}_K(V)$, can be considered as an $R$-module over itself.) The interpretation is that (after choosing a basis of $V$) elements of $V^n$ can be thought of as $n \times n$ matrices, where each of the $n$ summands in $V^n$ is to be thought of as a matrix column. From this perspective, the module action of $\operatorname{End}_K(V)$ on $V^n$ is then just matrix multiplication.

Comment: your answer about how each individual summands' basis elements serving as a column vector totally make sense.  The thing is I am really surprised how a lot of people can remember all these technical details of linear algebra, even though they don't use it everyday.  Thank you for your detail and clear explanations.

Comment: @SethMai Thanks!---though I confess one doesn't really remember all of these facts all of the time, but instead retains the ideas and basic pieces from which the arguments may be quickly reconstructed.

Comment: sorry, can i ask if you can provide a reference to the lemma you cited.  I looked across multiple sources online and also from various algebra text, and I did not came across it.

Comment: @SethMai No problem, but are you referring to a lemma in this answer or another one?

Comment: it is the lemma you used here:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4326057/a-finite-dimensional-vector-v-is-not-free-as-an-operatornameend-kv-mo/4326134#4326134

Comment: @SethMai Oh no problem please see my reply in chat.